# How to know the number of downloads of my apps from my itunes account

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

I have published an app to appstore , how can I know how many users downloaded the app? I cant find out an option for it.

Comment: how can know how much profit i get ?

Answer (score 4):

1. You can find the number in iTunes Connect.
2. Login to iTunes Connect.
3. Sales and Trends
4. Select the app and you can see daily, weekly and monthly sales/downloads.